# JScrollBar: the knob is not visible with small max values

Tags: java, eclipse, jscrollbar

I want to create a horizontal scrollbar whith max value set to 2 (it should allow only to choose 0, 1 or 2 as a value), but the knob is invisible if the value is smaller than 11.

```
    scrlLineDist = new JScrollBar();
    scrlLineDist.setBlockIncrement(1);
    scrlLineDist.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            System.out.println(scrlLineDist.getValue());
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_scrlLineDist = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_scrlLineDist.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_scrlLineDist.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_scrlLineDist.gridx = 0;
    gbc_scrlLineDist.gridy = 3;
    panel_4.add(scrlLineDist, gbc_scrlLineDist);
    scrlLineDist.setMaximum(2);
    scrlLineDist.setToolTipText("");
    scrlLineDist.setOrientation(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
```

When I change the `maximum` value to 12, it works the way I want (visible knob, values [0,2]). Why is this happening?

```
    scrlLineDist = new JScrollBar();
    scrlLineDist.setBlockIncrement(1);
    scrlLineDist.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
        public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
            System.out.println(scrlLineDist.getValue());
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_scrlLineDist = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_scrlLineDist.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_scrlLineDist.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_scrlLineDist.gridx = 0;
    gbc_scrlLineDist.gridy = 3;
    panel_4.add(scrlLineDist, gbc_scrlLineDist);
    scrlLineDist.setMaximum(12);
    scrlLineDist.setToolTipText("");
    scrlLineDist.setOrientation(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is probably a [`JSlider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html), not a `JScrollbar`.

```
// orientation, min, max, initial value
final JSlider slider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 2, 1);
slider.setSnapToTicks(true); // only allow 0, 1, 2 and not in between
slider.setPaintTicks(true); // paint ticks at tick spacing interval
slider.setMajorTickSpacing(1); // set interval to 1
slider.setPaintLabels(true); // show labels on ticks
```

Instead of a `AdjustmentListener`, add a `ChangeListener` to your slider, like so:

```
slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        // only output when value is set (when the mouse is released from the knob)
        // remove this if statement if you would like output whenever the knob is moved
        if(!slider.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            System.out.println(slider.getValue());
        }
    }

});
```

For more information about `JSlider`s, and an official tutorial, check out [The Java™ Tutorials - How to Use Sliders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html)